# Sed replace a string in the first line of a paragraph

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am trying to automate the periodic detection and elimination of files, using fdupes. I got this beautiful script:

```
# from here:
# https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-remove-duplicate-files-without-wasting-time/

OUTF=rem-duplicates_2019-01.sh;

echo "#! /bin/sh" > $OUTF;

find "$@" -type f -printf "%s\n" | sort -n | uniq -d |
    xargs -I@@ -n1 find "$@" -type f -size @@c -exec md5sum {} \; |
    sort --key=1,32 | uniq -w 32 -d --all-repeated=separate |
    sed -r 's/^[0-9a-f]*( )*//;s/([^a-zA-Z0-9./_-])/\\\1/g;s/(.+)/#rm \1/;' >> $OUTF;
chmod a+x $OUTF; ls -l $OUTF
```

This produces a file with this structure:

```
#! /bin/sh
#rm ./directory_a/file_a
#rm ./directory_b/file_identical_to_a

#rm ./directory_a/file_b
#rm ./directory_b/file_identical_to_b
#rm ./directory_c/another_file_identical_to_b

#rm ./directory_a/file_c
#rm ./directory_b/file_identical_to_c
#rm ./directory_c/another_file_identical_to_c
#rm ./directory_d/yet_another_file_identical_to_c
```

I want to remove the # tag from the first line of each paragraph to get

```
rm ./directory_a/file_c
#rm ./directory_b/file_identical_to_c
#rm ./directory_c/another_file_identical_to_c
#rm ./directory_d/yet_another_file_identical_to_c
```

I have been trying to modify the next-to-last line, with variations of things like this:

```
    sed -r 's/^[0-9a-f]*( )*//;s/([^a-zA-Z0-9./_-])/\\\1/g;s/(.+)/#rm \1/;s/\n\n#rm/\n\nrm/;' >> $OUTF;
```

But cannot manage SED to recognize the (\n\n) or any other pointer I can think of to the beginning of the paragraph. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I am unable to edit the comment, so here is the final script:

```
TEMPF=temp.txt;
OUTF=rem-duplic_2019-01.sh

echo "#! /bin/sh" > $TEMPF;

find "$@" -type f -printf "%s\n" | sort -n | uniq -d |
    xargs -I@@ -n1 find "$@" -type f -size @@c -exec md5sum {} \; |
    sort --key=1,32 | uniq -w 32 -d --all-repeated=separate |
    sed -r 's/^[0-9a-f]*( )*//;s/([^a-zA-Z0-9./_-])/\\\1/g;s/(.+)/#rm \1/' >> $TEMPF;
awk -v a=2 '/^$/{a=2}!--a{sub(/#/,"")}1' $TEMPF > $OUTF

chmod a+x $OUTF; ls -l $OUTF
rm $TEMPF
```

Comment: So the code you show is not what you try to achieve your goal, it only generates the input? Delete it. Shoe just the sample input. Then show your attempts at using sed to achieve the edits.

Comment: What do you want to do for the first paragraph whose first line is `#! /bin/sh`?

Comment: Edited the note to add one of the lines I tried and failed.

Comment: Thank you @oguzismail. The awk line worked like a charm. I included it fast-and-dirty in the script, maybe not the most elegant code, but it will do. The sed line gives me some strange results, but I'll have a look at it with more time.

Comment: Please make an answer (OP or @oguzismail). OP, i.e. yozzarian, please either remove the sed tag or add the awk tag if you like an answer based on a tool you did not tag/ask.

Comment: @Yunnosch added answer.

Comment: Why do you want to change the file after it's generated rather than just generating it in  the right format in the first place?

Comment: @EdMorton That would be great, but I cannot swim that deep yet. I was just trying to adapt a existing script, but if you have a suggestion for it I'd be grateful to see it.

Comment: I can't make a suggestion as I've no idea what the input to your script looks like, sorry. If you want help then post a new question with it's own sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use awk instead:

```
awk '/^$/{a=1} !a--{sub(/#/,"")} 1' a=1 file
```

- `/^$/ { a = 1 }` means set `a` to 1 if current line is a blank one,
- `!a--` is a shorthand for `a-- == 0`, following action (`{ sub(/#/, "") }`) removes the first `#` from current line,
- `1` means print all lines,
- `a=1` is required to remove `#` from the line after shebang (i.e 2nd line).

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed "1n;/^#/,/^$/{ s///;}" file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too:

```
sed '/^$\|^#!/{N;s/#r/r/}' input.txt
```

*feel free to add the in-place opt if you want*

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^#!\|^\s*$/{n;s/.//}' file
```

If the current line is a shebang or an empty line, print it and remove the first character of the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Perl with paragraph mode

```
perl -00 -pe ' s/^#// '
```

With inputs

```
$ cat yozzarian.txt
#! /bin/sh
#rm ./directory_a/file_a
#rm ./directory_b/file_identical_to_a

#rm ./directory_a/file_b
#rm ./directory_b/file_identical_to_b
#rm ./directory_c/another_file_identical_to_b

#rm ./directory_a/file_c
#rm ./directory_b/file_identical_to_c
#rm ./directory_c/another_file_identical_to_c
#rm ./directory_d/yet_another_file_identical_to_c
$ perl -00 -pe ' s/^#// ' yozzarian.txt
! /bin/sh
#rm ./directory_a/file_a
#rm ./directory_b/file_identical_to_a

rm ./directory_a/file_b
#rm ./directory_b/file_identical_to_b
#rm ./directory_c/another_file_identical_to_b

rm ./directory_a/file_c
#rm ./directory_b/file_identical_to_c
#rm ./directory_c/another_file_identical_to_c
#rm ./directory_d/yet_another_file_identical_to_c
$
```